# Changing color symbol legend by field

Tags: qgis, legend, color

I changed the color of the polygon symbology with a specified field. Now, I need to categorize the symbology for better data management and to be displayed on a map. But, this not change the legend color.

How can I change the color automatically so that the legend matches the map?
For example, in the figure below, the first element should be white but, is red.

Change colors manually is the only solution I can see. This is very tedious and it would no longer make sense to have changed them by specified field..

[image]

Comment: You should be able to force data driven colours for all symbols by setting it for the base symbol and then rerun the categorization. If this doesn't work, you will need to set to data driven colour for each category separately.

Comment: That's what I've done. But, when rerun the categorization, the colors no change. As well, I set to data driven color for separately, and neither. I will have to do it manually.

Comment: How exactly did you set to data driven?

Comment: Okay, so the issue "simply" is, that your legend doesn't look like the symbols on the map. That is rather annoying, to be fair, but since we seem to talk about 14 colours which you know the hex code of, it wont be that much work.

Comment: Yes. But, the idea is to automate the process.